# Simple MySQL query is too slow

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a 10 million record table in a MySQL 5.5 InnoDB. It's running in a 16GB RAM server with good CPU and fast HD. When I run the following query

```
SELECT DISTINCT knowledge_id, 
                tag_order, 
                tag_weight, 
                total_title_direct_words, 
                total_title_parenthesis_words, 
                tag_level 
FROM   knowledge_tags 
WHERE  ( tag_text = 'washington' ) 
       AND ( tag_level < 10 );
```

It will take around 9 seconds (first run) locally (localhost). The result count is 640. There is a Btree index for the fields 'tag_text, tag_level'. This query time isn't acceptable for what i want. What can I do?

Here is the EXPLAIN result:

```
1   SIMPLE  knowledge_tags  range   tags_by_word_text   tags_by_word_text   308 [null]  344 Using index condition; Using temporary
```

And the CREATE TABLE statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `knowledge_tags` (
  `tag_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `knowledge_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dictionary_word_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tag_text` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tag_order` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tag_level` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `knowledge_family_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tag_weight` double DEFAULT '1',
  `total_title_direct_words` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `total_title_parenthesis_words` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tag_id`),
  KEY `tags_by_knowledge_id` (`knowledge_id`),
  KEY `tags_by_word_text` (`tag_text`,`tag_level`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `tags_by_family_dictionary` (`knowledge_family_id`,`dictionary_word_id`,`tag_level`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `tags_by_family_word_text` (`knowledge_family_id`,`tag_text`,`tag_level`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `tags_by_dictionary` (`dictionary_word_id`,`tag_level`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3316 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: How long does the query take without the `distinct`?  Is the `distinct` needed?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Without the 'distinct' the time is almost the same. It's just a protection.

Comment: This question is perhaps more appropriate for dba.stackexchange.com.  But, are you sure the database server is configured correctly to use the memory on the machine?

Comment: Hmm, I can look into this further, but I'm not sure having a composite BTREE INDEX for tag_text + tag_level together is ideal. What's the reason you went with a composite key there? What's the cardinality of those columns?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'll check the configuration again but the setup was made to use all the available memory.

Comment: @omgitsfletch Not sure what you mean, but I believe that the "tags_by_word_text" index should handle this properly.

Comment: Can you run this: `SELECT * FROM  `knowledge_tags` PROCEDURE ANALYSE()` ? I want to get an idea for your data makeup to create some sample data and run some tests locally.